# In my Node.js + Express API I have an image as base64 string, how to send it to other api as multipart/form-data

Tags: node.js, image, api, post, base64

I am working on API which is like a bridge between a WCF service and a third party API. 
From my WCF service I am using newtonsoft library to convert C# object to JSON. It converts a byte array to a base64 string in UTF-8 formatting. 
So in My Node.js API I am receiving the image as base64 string,now I have to store the image in couchbase db (done) and send the image as multipart/form-data to a third-party API. How do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use the popular [`request`](https://github.com/request/request) library combined with `Buffer.from(base64Image, "base64")`:

```
const request = require("request");

const base64Image = ...

const formData = {
    exampleImage: {
        value: Buffer.from(base64Image, "base64"),
        options: {
            filename: "example-image.jpg",
            contentType: "image/jpeg"
        }
    }
};

const postOptions = {
    url: "http://www.test.com/upload",
    formData
};

request.post(postOptions, (err, httpResponse, body) => {

    if (err) {
        return console.error("Upload failed:", err);
    }

    console.log("Upload successful!");
});
```